# Form Data to PDF

Tags: javascript, html

I'm an HTML beginner and created a fairly complex HTML form with about 50 different questions and there's an HTML5 signature canvas at the end.  What would be the easiest way to take the form data and create a very good looking PDF from it and email it on the backend? I would need the signature to come over on the PDF as well.  This would be an insurance claim form so the PDF that gets generated would have to look good.  I'm even willing to pay for some software that is beginner friendly. I'm using jQuery UI Signature for the signature.  I have Linux cpanel access and was thinking of writing the info the a MySQL database and some how pulling the data from there?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was always using WkHtmlToPDF - it's free, it's open, it's based on Webkit. So you basically code a HTML that is designed using CSS, and then you run wkhtmltopdf on it and it generates almost 1:1 PDF.

Find more info here:
http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Another you can use is for example mPDF, i was using mPDF some times, since it is really easy to install (It's one PHP class only, you just import it), and you can lock the PDFs using password.

More info here:
http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Comment: Thanks let's say for instance I wanted to test WkHtmlToPDF.  I don't see that application listed in GoDaddy's Linux cPanel.  Am I limited to only what they show or how would I add this additional application?

Comment: WkHtmlToPDF must be installed as binary on the host, so either you may ask GoDaddy to install it for you (but they will probably refuse), or you can try mPDF - to install mPDF, you only download few PHP classes and import them via FTP to your webroot directory. Then you include them in your project and you work with them as with PHP objects. No support from GoDaddy needed.